# How to convert a std::chrono::duration<double,std::milli> to a double

Tags: c++11

I am finding `std::chrono` somewhat confusing and obstructive. I want to use real-valued milliseconds and end up with values like 0.7 or 6.45 or 13.3 that I can treat as `double` values.

I really just want to start from two `time_point` values and return the elapsed time between them as a `double`. How? This does not work:

```
using std;
using std::chrono;
high_resolution_clock::time_point t1( high_resolution_clock::now() );
// spend some time doing something...
high_resolution_clock::time_point t2( high_resolution_clock::now() );
const duration<double,milli> elapsedTime( t2 - t1 );
const double timeAsDouble( static_cast<double>( elapsedTime ) ); // no conversion available :-(
// go on to use or return timeAsDouble;
```

IMPORTANT CONSTRAINT: I specifically **do not** want to use values of type `std::chrono::duration<double,std::milli>`. Why not? Because I will immediately square the values I want to work with. When I square a `double`, I know it is a generic type, meaning that it is taking care of the number only, and not the units. So I have to explicitly take care of the units myself (e.g. by being clear about it in the variable name, even though this is prone to slip-ups).

But if I wanted to square a `std::chrono::duration<double,std::milli>`, I would open a can of worms either with regard to the units or to code clarity. In any case, no `*` operator is defined for multiplying this class by itself, so the second line in the example below avoids questions about its units and type by simply not compiling at all:

```
auto timeSpan( duration<double,std::milli>( 0.8 ) );
auto spanSquared( timeSpan*timeSpan );    // ???
```

So what is the easy way to turn what looks like it should be a `double`... into a `double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `std::chrono::duration<...>::count()`?

Also, it's worth mentioning that a reason for the absense of multiplication operator is quite obvious: when you multiply values, you multiply units as well, e.g. *10 seconds x 10 seconds = 100 **square** seconds*. Which, in it's turn leads to a bazillion of problems, like unit conversion (e.g. *1 square second = 1000000 square milliseconds*, not 1000), which are far out of scope of what std::chrono was intended for.

Comment: Could you provide a source for this answer? I've been wondering what the return type of count() was for a while and always just use auto. All I can find is this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/count.